# does stellio-context-broker support fiware-service?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-stellio

I'm porting an OrionLD based context-broker to stellio and it uses fiware-service to separate out different tenants. When I set this up in stellio request headers, stellio doesn't appear to acknowledge them and all the tenants end up in the group.

Does stellio use a different mechanism for this?

Comment: Orion-LD supports both NGSIv2 (+v1), and NGSI-LD. The name of the HTTP header for NGSI-LD is "NGSILD-Tenant", but, for backwards compatibility, Orion-LD supports also "FIWARE-Service". Now, I don't know whether Stellio has developed the support for tenants. I know who to ask though (question sent already), and I'll be back with more info once I get an answer. What I can say almost for sure is that Stellio won't ever support FIWARE-Service - wouldn't make much sense ... So, for now, try with NGSILD-Tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Stellio does not yet implement the support for NGSI-LD Tenants (the NGSI-LD equivalent of FIWARE-Service, as explained by @kzangelin above). This is however quite high in our priority list, and we expect to do it this summer.